# Draw hourglass in random coordinates

Tags: java, random, draw, geometric-arc

Hey I need to draw an hourglass in different locations each time I start my app. I tried this way:

```
Random randomNum = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

int a1=randomNum.nextInt(500);
int a2=a1*2;
int a3=a1;
int a4=a2;

int b1=a1;
int b2=a2/2;
int b3=a2/2;
int b4=a1;

int x1points[] = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
int y1points[] = {b1, b2, b3, b4};

int ntpoints = 4;
g.fillPolygon(x1points, y1points, ntpoints);
```

Hourglass isn't visible this way. Any advices? Everything's fine with JFrame & JPanel (another geometrics are showed right way).

Comment: Verify the values of the coordinates, for example your b-values will all be the same and a2=2*a1 does not look correct either.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Where is your `Graphics g` coming from? (That is, are you painting this in a `paintComponent` method?)